# Posting comments to Facebook Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented the Facebook Comments API using the documentation provided at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

The problem is that this uses my Facebook App and not my Facebook Company Fan Page.

I cannot seem to find any documentation telling me how to change this.

I want people to comment on my website and post the comments to my Facebook fan page (NOT my Facebook App)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.
First you have to customize the comment plugin for your page by filling "URL to comment on" textbox with your Facebook Page URL.

To get comments made, you should use Graph API. The URL that you can request with a valid acces token is `https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_OBJECT_ID/comments`